# setInterval fires multiple times and possibly messing up component rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm developing this small dashboard type site in Nuxtjs 3 to display some stats, and I want two components to swap with each other every so often, so I decided to make use of setInterval in Typescript.

For some reason, the setInterval function fires its code multiple times and I think it's messing with the components rendering.

edit: It's only displaying the first component (cards) and when i changes to 1 nothing happens

edit2: so somehow the setinterval has returned back to normal but the component won't switch still?

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
        <component :is="i==0 ? cards : zendesk"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import cards from '~~/components/cards/cards.vue';
import zendesk from "~~/components/zendesk.vue";
let comps: any = []
comps.push(cards, zendesk)

let i = ref(0)

const time = 2 

setInterval(() =>  {
    i.value++
    if (i.value >= comps.length) {
        i.value = 0
    }
}, time * 1000) 

</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` will fire (and thus create a new interval) every time you render that component.

Comment: @derpirscher component as in the whole file or the ones I'm importing?

Comment: Whenever that particular part you are showing here is rendered ...

Comment: @derpirscher this part is the entirety of my index.vue file. Is this being rendered multiple times somehow?

Comment: "Is this being rendered multiple times somehow?" - put a `console.log`, or a breakpoint, right before `setInterval` and you'll know the answer.

Comment: @mbojko one console log gets outputted. im honestly lost

Comment: Depending on the browser, muliple equal console.logs may be grouped together. Only a counter indicates how often this output really happened. And if there is realy only one output, `setInterval` will only be called once. But of course, the callback will be called repeatedly until you clear the interval ... In your case every two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up a `setInterval` to prevent duplication.

You must keep in mind that any code you write during development (serve) is subject to re-execution on hot-reload events and any global state functions like timeouts or event bindings will continue exist and a duplicate created, the same applies to leaving a routed component and returning to it later or componenets wrapped in `v-if` and toggled on/off repeatedly.

You must use the destruction/exit hooks provided by vue, vue-router etc to clean up externals.

`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `addEventListner`

These must me cleaned up in destruction/exit hooks using their counterparts:

`clearTimeout`, `clearInterval`, `removeEventListner`

```js
<script setup>

const i = ref(0)
let interval = null

onMounted(() => {
  interval = setInterval(() =>  {
    i.value++
    if (i.value >= comps.length) {
        i.value = 0
    }
  }, time * 1000) 
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  clearInterval(interval)
}) 

<script>
```

How to clean up event binds

```
<script setup>

const onResize = () => {
  console.log('I resized')
}

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListner('resize', onResize)
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  window.removeEventListner('resize', onResize)
})
</script>
```

P.S.
`i` can be a `const` because `i` it's self never changes it is always of type `ref`, what changes is the inner value of `ref`.

Comment: cheers for the answer and extra advice. i think its been cleaned up but the component is still not changing, so it might be a different issue.